# BSOD : DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Tags: linux, windows-10, drivers, bsod

I have a laptop **ASUS X550JK**, I get the **BSOD** with **DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE**, it happens randomly, Before the BSOD occurs, I notice a rise in CPU temperature and the fan makes noise

[image]

When I check the **dump file**, I get this :

[image]

---

**What I've tried:**

1. I've tried to install Windows 10 with *USB* and *CD/DVD Drive* as
   well, but the same issue happened every time.
2. I've updated all drivers (using **Driver Booster**,**Driver
   Reviver** and **DriverPack solution**).
3. I've changed some Power settings.

---

**NOTE:** With  Linux (**Ubuntu 19.04** & **Mint**), everything works just fine, I've used Linux for 1 week, and I didn't face any issue with it.

Can anyone help me to get resolve this issue, I've spent a lot of time to solve it with no success

Comment: There are a number of causes for this. Below is a very technical Microsoft explanation. Update BIOS, Chipset, Power and Video drivers with the PC Vendor's drivers. Run DISM (dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth) followed by SFC .  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x9f--driver-power-state-failure

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the Asus website does not provide the drivers,also I've run the DISM cmd, and I get (Operation complete succefully)

Comment: At this point, then, consider a Windows 10 Repair Install (Media Creation Link) at a point when Windows 10 is running, OR, back up and reinstall Windows. Too many possibilities and things that may have gone wrong